# Opening Selenium Webdriver tests in the same window

Tags: java, browser, selenium, webdriver

I have dozens of Selenium Webdriver tests. I want to run them all at once. How do I run the test so that each test does not open a new Webdriver browser window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initiate/teardown  your webdriver in a @BeforeClass/@AfterClass, and use this webdriver in all your test.

```
public class MyTest {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubAddress), capability);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void setDownClass() {
         driver.quit();
    }

    @Test 
    public void Test1(){
         driver.get(...);
    }

    @Test 
    public void Test2(){
         driver.get(...):
    }
}
```

Or make it static in an TestSuite, with the same @BeforeClass/@AfterClass :

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class})
public class MyTestSuite {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubAddress), capability);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void setDownClass() {
         driver.quit();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Test1 {

    @Test 
    public void Test1(){
         MyTestSuite.driver.get(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work, when you have @Test-methods in different java classes? They have to be, because there are so many tests.

Comment: But you have to list all the classes in @SuiteClasses anotation? No way to just include all classes in test package?