# ClassNameFilter and BeforeClass

Tags: java, browser, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have dozens of Selenium Webdriver tests. I want to run them all at once. How do I run the test so that each test does not open a new Webdriver browser window?

Is a solution something like this possible? This causes nullPointError from driver.

```
      @ClassnameFilters({"com.company.package*", ".*Test"})

 public class TestSuite {

 public static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@AfterClass
public static void setDownClass() {
     driver.quit();
}
```

}

```
  public class Test {

private WebDriver driver = TestSuite.driver;

 @Test.... {
    }
```

Putting the new object initialization attribute gets the first test running, but then the others cause unreachable browser error. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

hah, sorry for my inattentiveness.
*This causes nullPointError from driver* that can be caused only by improper web driver initialization.
As you declare `public static WebDriver driver;`  in  `public class TestSuite` and create instance in

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

you don't need in

`public class Test`

initialize

`private WebDriver driver = TestSuite.driver;` once  again.
Instead of it I would use inheritance `public class Test` from `public class TestSuite` in the following way and in my tests annotated by `@Test` simply called my driver as it is initialized as static. Code be like:

```
public class Test extends TestSuite {
@Test
public void findButtonAndClickOnIt(){
String buttonCssSelector ="...blablabla...";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(buttonCssSelector)).click();
}
}
```

hope now it works for you.

Comment: No, this is not quite working for me yet. I also need to run each tests separately - each test has to have its own class. In this situation beforeClass works the same way as After, and the window is closed after every test. Other problem is, that the window closes to quickly. I've tried   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4000, TimeUnit.SECONDS); but it does not help.

Comment: in my project I use hierarchy I described in post. I have basic class where we got driver initialization and some other classes with tests inheriting from this basic class. One class contains a pack of tests. So If you run a pack of tets which are contained in the boundary of one class - u got one driver instance. If you wanna get a class for each test then a lot of instances of drivers will be created. One instance for each class. IMHO it better to put a pack of tests in one class so only one driver instance will be created. Except this, I do not see alternative solution to your issue.

Answer (score -1):

to handle this issue try using  `@BeforeClass, @AfterClass` annotation:

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class BaseSeleniumTest extends SeleneseTestBase {
static WebDriver driver;


@Value("login.base.url")
private String loginBaseUrl;

@BeforeClass
public static void firefoxSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {

   DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();


    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.52:4444/wd/hub"), capability);


    driver = new FirefoxDriver();  //for local check

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
}
@Before
public void openFiretox() throws IOException {


    driver.get(propertyKeysLoader("login.base.url"));


}


@AfterClass
public static void closeFirefox(){
    driver.quit();
}
```

....

@BeforeClass means that you initialize something and all the following selenium tests annotated by `@Test` be run in a single browser window open.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Stéphane Piette, it seems to me you leave intentional downvote on the answer to the question u've already answered to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833847/opening-selenium-webdriver-tests-in-the-same-window/12834238#12834238
Speaking on the point, the author of the question has faced such problem because of improper driver initialization in 'public class Test '. And you Stéphane Piette, didn't provide any basis for my answer be inproper or incorrect as I provided 100% working piece of code I use for my purposes.
Best regards.